# Как обработать пуш в фоновом режиме, если он послан из консоли firebase?

Tags: android, push-уведомления, fcm

Мне нужно обработать пуш уведомление присланное из консоли firebase(желание заказчика). В сети везде пишут, что в фоновом режиме пуши без секции data не перехватываются обработчиком, однако мне настойчиво утверждают, что это уже было реализовано. Существуют ли какие либо способы для этого?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109786/discussion-on-question-by-anton-charov-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработать не получится. Если под `обработать` имеется в виду вызов вашего кода по приходу уведомления с получением всей информации о пуше и без ужасных костылей, позволяющих сажая постоянно батарейку и раздражая юзера отслеживать текст уведомления.

Однако ТС имеет в виду запуск своего кода после нажатия на уведомление с получением данных, отосланных из консоли. В этом случае надо действовать по стандартному сценарию обработки нажатия на любое уведомление:

1. В зависимости от `launchMode` активити и того открыта ли она сейчас получить данные из `getIntent().getExtras()` в `onCreate` и/или `onNewIntent(Intent intent)`.
2. В `Bundle` придут данные, посланные из консоли - вот на них можно уже как-то отреагировать, например открыть к-л экран.